# SQL Group by statement for mysql

Tags: sql

My SQL knowledge is quite rusty and I need some support.
We have an MySQL database on which we save all RPMs from all Hosts in our estate.

Table is like this:

| Hostname | OS | rpms | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| host1 | Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9 | .. | .. |  |
| host1 | Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9 | .. | .. |  |
| host1 | Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9 | .. | .. |  |
| host2 | Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 | .. | .. |  |
| host2 | Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 | .. | .. |  |
| host2 | Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 | .. | .. |  |

What I need is to get the number of hosts per OS version.

I tried this:

```sql
select os, count(os) from allhosts 
group by os
order by os;
```

but of course is totally wrong, since it will return thousands of records per OS since the DB has **all** the RPMs that are installed on *each* host.

I would appreciate some help to unstuck myself from this.

What I am looking for, is something like this:

| Hostname | OS |
| --- | --- |
| Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.9 | 240 |
| Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 | 702 |

Comment: Where are you stuck? Please tag the appropriate database.

Comment: Simply `count(distinct os)`?